Difficulty Understanding Transition Between Matrix Equations in the Paper
I'm not sure whether it is okay to ask about some equations in the paper.
The authors presented some matrix equations, but I cannot follow them.
Is there anyone who can explain this manipulation of matrices?
$Given : ~~~W_o\in R^{d\times k},~x_{i} \in R^{d\times1},~B_{i} \in R^{d\times 1} ,~ A_{i}\in R^{1\times k}, ~W_{i}=\Delta W_{i} \odot W_{0}, \Delta W_{i}=B_{i}A_{i}.$
Note that $\odot$ is a hadamard product (elementwise multiplication).
$y_{i}=W^{T}_{i}x_{i}  ~~ (2)$
$~~~=(W^{T}_{0} \odot \Delta W^{T}_{i})x_{i}  ~~ (3)$
$~~~=(W^{T}_{0} \odot (B_{i}A_{i})^{T})x_{i}  ~~ (4)$
$~~~=(A_{i} \odot (W^{T}_{0}(B_{i} \odot x_{i})))(5)$
How is the identity from (4) to (5) satisfied?
I can follow the steps from (2) to (4).
Should the $A_{i}$ in (5) be $A^{T}_{i}$?
Still, I cannot understand the step from (4) to (5).

If checking (2) against (5) in terms of dimensions, then
(2): $W^{T}_{i}x_{i} \in R^{k\times 1}$
(5): $(A_{i} \odot (W^{T}_{0}(B_{i} \odot x_{i}))) \in "R^{1\times k} \odot R^{k\times 1}"$
However one evaluates the Hadamard product of a column vector and a row vector, I believe something got messed up with the equations.

yes, I agree with you. That's why I suspect that the transpose notation T for A is not marked correctly in (5). However, I still can't follow the step from (4) to (5).
